# Ordinal probit model misses one category of independent variable

Tags: likert, probit

I am running an ordinal probit model in STATA. the independent variable is a discrete variable and have 2 options )1,2,3) and so i place a prefix i before it. The results show the parameters for 2 and 3, and omits the first option. Same omit of parameters continue when i calculate margins for each levels.Why is STATA doing so?

Possible reasons and suggestions are needed.

Comment: Is this a question about the dummy variable trap? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29

Comment: How can i check multicollinearity for ordinal probit model in STATA?

Comment: Sorry, not a STATA user. In any case, asking for code is off-topic on CV.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have indeed find the ans. it wasn't coz of multicolinearity, the lowest category is used as refrence category by STATA =0 hence it omits it.In my case 1 is used as refrence category and it gives parameters for 2 and 3 .